# Django group by and order by

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have comment table with following fields. Here, first row means, 3rd comment in the database belongs to post 1. Second and third row means, 3rd and 4th comments belongs to post 1 and they are also replies to the 2nd comment and so on.

```
id    post_id   comment_id  date
 2     1                     ...
 3     1          2          ...
 4     1          2          ...
 5     1                     ...
 6     1          5          ...
```

I would like to do a django group by query so such that,
to get all the comments of post 1 and group them by the replies to a comment. So I would expect groups like this

```
group1: comment2: comment3,4
group2: comment5: comment6
```

The group query should also be ordered by date field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following declaration for `Comment`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    replying_to = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date = models.DateField()
    text = models.TextField(default='')

grouped_comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('replying_to', 'date)
```

You said that you want to:

> get all the comments of post 1 and group them by the replies to a comment

The above `grouped_comments` returns all comments grouped as you want.  If you just want comments for a specific post, then, of course, just filter on `post` (use your own selection criteria for the post - I've hard-coded `id` below):

```
grouped_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post__id=1).order_by('replying_to', 'date)
```

**However**, when you go to render the above, I think that you're not going to be able to do what you want.  You're rendering a tree, and I don't know of a way to do this with querysets.  You might want to look at [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  It has [template tags for recursive rendering](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html).

Comment: I'd add a prefetch_related in your querset definition to speed things up!

Comment: So, basically this is what I need `SELECT * from comments order by coalesce(comment_id, id), (case when comment_id is null then 1 else 2 end), id;`. What would be the equivalent of this in django?